# Using Aliases with two Joins on MS-Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting to add Joins that will allow the query to display the corresponding `tbl_ICA.[Abbreviation]` for both `tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA]` and `tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA]` in each record.

(tables are related as shown [here](https://imgur.com/UopVnmT_d.jpg))

I can get a single Join to work fine, but when I add the second I get

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 't1.[ICA #]=t.[From ICA] INNER JOIN t1 As t2 ON t2.[ICA #]=t.[To ICA'

It seems like it isn't recognizing the second JOIN as another function. I need the aliases as I'm selecting two different instances of `.[Abbreviation]`.

Query:

```
SELECT t.[Assy ID], t1.[Abbreviation], t.[From ICA], t2.[Abbreviation], t.[To ICA], t.[To Loc], t.[Date], t.Comments
FROM tbl_AssyMoves As t
INNER JOIN tbl_ICAs As t1
     ON t1.[ICA #]=t.[From ICA]
INNER JOIN t1 As t2
     ON t2.[ICA #]=t.[To ICA]
WHERE ((t.Date Between [Forms]![Form1]![StartDate] And [Forms]![Form1]![EndDate])
**note, additional WHERE criteria omitted for brevity**
```

Comment: In MS Access, more than one `JOIN` requires parentheses pairings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access syntax is different than other dbms when it comes to joins (among other things). 
Requires parentheses:

```
SELECT t.[Assy ID], t1.[Abbreviation], t.[From ICA], t2.[Abbreviation], t.[To ICA], t.[To Loc], t.[Date], t.Comments
FROM (tbl_AssyMoves As t INNER JOIN tbl_ICAs As t1 ON t1.[ICA #]=t.[From ICA])
INNER JOIN t1 As t2 ON t2.[ICA #]=t.[To ICA]
WHERE ((t.Date Between [Forms]![Form1]![StartDate] And [Forms]![Form1]![EndDate])
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. For some reason it wouldn't recognize the t1 alias (gave an error saying table t1 couldn't be found). But, I just removed that alias and kept t2 and it worked fine.

Comment: I think instead of `INNER JOIN t1 AS t2` it should be `INNER JOIN tbl_ICAs AS t2`